# group by one field and count the matching fields

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a triple join that looks like this:

```
   select DATE_FORMAT(Posts.PostDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), (Tags.TagName)
    from Posts
    join PostTags
            on Posts.PK_PostID = PostTags.FK_PostID
        join Tags
            on Tags.PK_TagID = PostTags.FK_TagID
    where Tags.TagName = 'Money'
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

But I want it to be grouped by the date, and then next to it the number of times the tag is used. I can't figure it out. Something like this:

```
2012-12-26 10
2012-12-27 4
```

Comment: can you post a sql fiddle?

Comment: What if there are multiple rows in table with same postdate but with different tagnames?  What do you want query to output then?

Comment: @CharlesBretana his where clause is where the selection happens, at least in this specific query.

Comment: What is the datatype of `Posts.PostDate`, is it `DATE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a fiddle, I believe what you want is this:

```
    select DATE_FORMAT(Posts.PostDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), count(Tags.TagName)
    from Posts
    join PostTags
            on Posts.PK_PostID = PostTags.FK_PostID
        join Tags
            on Tags.PK_TagID = PostTags.FK_TagID
    where Tags.TagName = 'Money'
    group by DATE_FORMAT(Posts.PostDate, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: probably want to group by `DATE(Posts.PostDate)` in case it contains the time as well.

Comment: Thanks, I made a small edit at the group by, it should be the same DATE_FORMAT as used on the first line.

Comment: this will count all tagnames for a given postdate, not the count for each tagnmae

Comment: @Veltar Ah yes, wasn't even thinking about how format could impact this.

Comment: @CharlesBretana Not sure I see the issue there?  OP wants this:  2012-12-26 10   meaning how many times was `Money` seen on the 26th, which would be 10

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your tables, but try this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(Posts.PostDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as PDate, COUNT(*) FROM Posts
JOIN PostTags ON Posts.PK_PostID = PostTags.FK_PostID
JOIN Tags ON Tags.PK_TagID = PostTags.FK_TagID 
WHERE Tags.TagName = 'Money'
GROUP BY PDate
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html for more detail

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple aggregation query.  I've chosen to write it by using your query as a subquery, although this is not strictly necessary:

```
select thedate,
       sum(case when tagname = 'Money' then 1 else 0 end) as NumMoney
from (select DATE_FORMAT(Posts.PostDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as thedate, (Tags.TagName)
      from Posts join
           PostTags
           on Posts.PK_PostID = PostTags.FK_PostID join
           Tags
           on Tags.PK_TagID = PostTags.FK_TagID
     ) t
group by thedate
```

Answer (score 0):

well you have to use a group By clause, and if the tag name is in the output, you must gropup by the tag name as well. (otherwise, if there are multiple rows with same date but different tag names, which tag name should be output for the one row with any specific date?....

```
 select DATE_FORMAT(p.PostDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), (t.TagName), 
      Count(Distinct t.tagname) tagCount
 from Posts p
     join PostTags pt
        on pt.FK_PostID - p.PK_PostID 
     join Tags t
        on t.PK_TagID = pt.FK_TagID
 group by DATE_FORMAT(p.PostDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), (t.TagName)
```

If there can be multiple rows with same date but different tag names, you want the count for each distinct tagName, then you need to group by tagname too.   is this what you want ?

Comment: Based on his original I don't think he cares about the tag name, just the number of times the tag in his where clause was seen per date.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to SUB-SELECT the group by as follows:

```
SELECT T.*, Tags.TagName
FROM (select DATE_FORMAT(Posts.PostDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), PostTags.FK_TagID, count(*) PostsCount
from Posts
join PostTags
        on Posts.PK_PostID = PostTags.FK_PostID
group by DATE_FORMAT(Posts.PostDate, '%Y-%m-%d'), PostTags.FK_TagID) as P
inner join Tags
        on Tags.PK_TagID = P.FK_TagID
```